# Backlight flickering at low brightness levels

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, backlight

I noticed my phone's backlight would start to flicker/pulse intermittently when I switch my brightness level to something low (est. between 1% to 15% brightness). The flickering or pulsing is as if the power supplied to the light is fluctuating.

My phone is a HTC Desire, OS used to be stock (Froyo 2.2) when I experienced this, now it is on CM7.2 (GB 2.3.7), still has this problem. I have not tried any other ROMs on this phone, and not sure if it is a software or a hardware problem.

Is there any way to prevent this flickering, other than not setting the brightness to such levels?

Comment: Did you change your display?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this [fix](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/tweak-available-for-correcting-auto-brightness-problem-of-htc-desire-with-cynogen-mod/)

> Those running the cynogen mod on their HTC Desire and experiencing problems with auto adjustment of brightness would be happy to hear that a fix has been developed to tackle it.

If it doesn't work you could try another rom to determine if its a software or a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the brightness that low on your device, try an "overlay" dimmer which displays a dark layer over the screen to simulate darker brightness. To you it will be the same.

Try [Lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS52aXRvLmx1eC5mcmVlIl0.). It will let you pick how low to let the brightness goes (just before flickering), then it will activate the overlay beyond that.